# ACF Pro options REST API route not working

Tags: wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have an options page setup in ACF with "Show In REST API" enabled. When I use `/wp-json/wp/v2/options`, I receive the following output:

> {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}

I've tried flushing the permalinks with not luck.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from [this post](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/options-page-in-rest-api-2/#post-160315) and got it working after I fixed a syntax issue in the original code that caused a fatal error.

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
  register_rest_route("options", "/all", [
    "methods" => "GET",
    "callback" => "acf_options_route",
  ]);
});
function acf_options_route() {
  return get_fields('options');
}
```

Endpoint: {site}/wp-json/options/all

To get target a particular repeater field, you can modify it like this:

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
  register_rest_route("options", "/team", [
    "methods" => "GET",
    "callback" => "acf_options_route",
  ]);
});
function acf_options_route() {
  return get_field('team_members', 'options');
}
```

Endpoint: {site}/wp-json/options/team